# How to get all table names in android sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have tried this code

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'",null);
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isAfterLast()){
    Toast.makeText(activityName.this, "Table Name=> "+c.getString(0), 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But it throws the error:

```
"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: sqlite_master(code 1):, while 
compiling: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"
```

How to fetch all the table names?

Comment: aren't you supposed to know the name of the tables in your database ?

Comment: i want to create table dynamically which are not created in database therfor I want to existing table name in my database. like show table in mysql

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Checked, tested and functioning. Try this code:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
        Toast.makeText(activityName.this, "Table Name=> "+c.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

I am assuming, at some point down the line, you will to grab a list of the *table names* to display in perhaps a `ListView` or something. Not just show a Toast.

*Untested code. Just what came at the top of my mind. Do test before using it in a production app. ;-)*

In that event, consider the following changes to the code posted above:

```
ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
            arrTblNames.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't understand how your query is any different ?

Comment: Hello Folks @siddharthLele query will work for iOS Sqlite also, like 
FMResultSet *s=[database executeQuery:@"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"];
while ([s next])
    {
         NSLog(@"%@",[s stringForColumn:@"name"]);
        
    }
and iterate by string name.
 Happy Coding

Comment: @Pilpel: I don't see something missing. If you have tested and found something missing, do let me know and I will fix it.

Answer (score 11):

Change your sql string to this one:

`"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name!='android_metadata' order by name"`

Answer (score 8):

To get **table name** with **list of all column** of that table

```
    public void getDatabaseStructure(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
            ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            int i = 0;
            result.add(c.getColumnNames());
            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                String[] temp = new String[c.getColumnCount()];
                for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                    temp[i] = c.getString(i);
                    System.out.println("TABLE - "+temp[i]);


                    Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(
                            "SELECT * FROM "+temp[i], null);
                    c1.moveToFirst();
                    String[] COLUMNS = c1.getColumnNames();
                    for(int j=0;j<COLUMNS.length;j++){
                        c1.move(j);
                        System.out.println("    COLUMN - "+COLUMNS[j]);
                    }
                }
                result.add(temp);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the schema before the table

schema.sqlite_master

From [SQL FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html)

> If you are running the sqlite3 command-line access program you can type ".tables" to get a list of all tables. Or you can type ".schema" to see the complete database schema including all tables and indices. Either of these commands can be followed by a LIKE pattern that will restrict the tables that are displayed.
>
> From within a C/C++ program (or a script using Tcl/Ruby/Perl/Python bindings) you can get access to table and index names by doing a SELECT on a special table named "SQLITE_MASTER". Every SQLite database has an **SQLITE_MASTER table that defines the schema for the database**. The SQLITE_MASTER table looks like this:
>
> CREATE TABLE sqlite_master (
>     type TEXT,
>     name TEXT,
>     tbl_name TEXT,
>     rootpage INTEGER,
>     sql TEXT
>   );

Comment: Thanks :( but I have already created schema but still not working Could you paste code of getting all table name from sqlite database android

Comment: Try what @Siddharth Lele mentioned. He added a condition because you do not know if you are going to receive any result. If it fails then replace the cursor query: `Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM your_schema.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);`

Comment: Thanks, but i have already tried with my_schema.sqlite_master but it didn't work. And thanks for your valuable response.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table";
```

Comment: This seems to be just a fragment of the code in the question. In general, starting with “Try this” suggests that the responder did not try it himself.

Answer (score 0):

I tested Siddharth Lele answer with Kotlin and Room, and it works as well.

The same code but using Kotlin and Room is something like that:

```
val cursor = roomDatabaseInstance.query(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name NOT IN ('android_metadata', 'sqlite_sequence', 'room_master_table')"))
val tableNames = arrayListOf<String>()
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
      tableNames.add(cursor.getString(0))
      cursor.moveToNext()
   }
}
```