# How to get column names with Active Android

Tags: android, activeandroid

With Active Android, can I get the column names of a table as a `String[]`?
`RawQuery()` returns a `List<Model>` so I can't just plug `PRAGMA` into it.

The suggested duplicate is about getting table names, and not related to Active Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all table names in android sqlite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383847/how-to-get-all-table-names-in-android-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these methods to get a collection of `Field`s:

```
public static synchronized TableInfo Cache.getTableInfo(Class<? extends Model> type);
public Collection<Field> TableInfo.getFields();
```

Then use `public String TableInfo.getColumnName(Field field)` on each `Field` to get column names. Example:

```
TableInfo<> userInfo = Cache.getTableInfo(User.class);
Collection<Field> fields = userInfo.getFields();
Set<String> columnNames = new HashSet<>();

for (Filed field : fields) {
    String name = userInfo.getColumnName(field);
    columnNames.add(name);
}
```

If you need to get id column name, use:

```
public String TableInfo.getIdName();
```

Comment: My own answer works but yours is probably better since a `Field` can probably have more uses.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after searching some more I found out I will need to deal with a `Cursor`, and I can get that by using `Cache`.

Like this:

```
Cursor c = Cache.openDatabase().rawQuery(new Select().from(User.class).toSql(),null);
String[] col = c.getColumnNames();
```

Comment: Use more ActiveAndroid :) `"SELECT * FROM Users"` -> `new Select().from(User.class).toSql();`

Comment: @naXa Sorry I don't understand, how can `Select()` get me a `Cursor`?

Comment: I mean, it would get you a `String` (see `toSql()`?). IMHO it would be better to avoid hardcoded SQL statements.