# How do I see my tables in SQLite Manager?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wrote code for database sqlite in android studio, but I don't know how to see my tables in sqlite manager.

Comment: Where did you put your SQLite database file? Is it on your device? You should be able to browse to your device and open the file with the SQLite manager - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android)? Or just how to see tables in general?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15384267/5612089)

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
        Toast.makeText(activityName.this, "Table Name=> "+c.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

You can do whatever you want from table name