# Room database - get table name at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Suppose I declare my entity like so:

```
@Entity(tableName = "banana")
data class MyStuff(
@PrimaryKey val id: String
)
```

When Room KAPT does it's magic, `@Entity` annotation is stripped so it is no longer there at runtime.

E.g. if I write `MyStuff::class.annotations` it returns empty list.

If I used `@Entity(tableName = "banana")` so my table name does NOT match my class name, how can I query Room database to find out that a given entity type means a given table name?

**UPDATE**

So I found a workaround albeit horrific.

It seems that Room actually has no knowledge about mapping between the Entity and the Table.
This information is compiled into the BODY of the DAO.

This is also why they make you use DAOs for all your tables which is very verbose.

Nevertheless, through some other needs I have the following annotation in my project:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class DaoType(val type: KClass<*>)
```

I also have a method to `getDao` from a `KClass<*>`.

All my DAO objects include an autogenerated deleteAll method like so:

```
    @Delete
    fun deleteAll(vararg entities: MyStuff)
```

Given that, I can get the table name like so:

```
var tableName: String? = null

val daoType = (entityType.annotations.firstOrNull { it is DaoType } as? DaoType)
                ?.type
daoType?.let {
    val dao = getDao<Any>(it.java)
    dao?.let { d ->
        val statementFields: List<Field> =
            d::class.java.declaredFields.filter { f ->
                return@filter f.type.declaredMethods.firstOrNull { m -> m.name == "createQuery" } != null
            }
        for (field in statementFields) {
            field.isAccessible = true
            val fieldVal = field.get(d) ?: continue
            val method = field.type.declaredMethods.first { m -> m.name == "createQuery" }
            val query = method.invoke(fieldVal) as? String ?: continue
            if (query.startsWith("DELETE FROM ")) {
                var matchResult = "DELETE\\sFROM\\s`(.*?)`.*".toRegex().find(query)
                val table = matchResult?.groupValues?.lastOrNull()
                if (table != null) {
                    tableName = table
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I am not marking this an accepted answer because I am not happy about the level of dependency on the inner workings of Room.

Still, this works at least now.

Comment: Just curious to know, Why do you want to know your table name at run time?

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya I have over 100 tables in the database. I have common tasks that are e.g. 'count rows in a table' or 'delete all rows from table' etc. I don't want to keep duplicating these methods in DAO. (it's bad enough we need DAO in the first place).

Comment: you can pass a parameter(eg. table name) with DAO and do the needful just like how ContentResolver.query() works by passing table name, selection projection....

Comment: Room uses Sqlite under the hood so you should be able to utilise one of the approaches in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383847/how-to-get-all-table-names-in-android-sqlite-database

Comment: @IvanWooll of course I can get the table name. How do I know which Kotlin class the table corresponds to?

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya of course if I want to declare it elsewhere (constant, other annotation, parameter...) I can. I want to use what I have already declared in `@Entity`

Comment: @zaitsman maybe keep a mapping of table names to class names? It seems like whichever way you choose to go, you're going to have to do some work :)

Comment: @IvanWooll not quite, see my last edit ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like :-

```
@Entity(tableName = MyStuff.tableName)
data class MyStuff(
    @PrimaryKey  val id: String
) {
    companion object {
        const val tableName = "banana"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah now i need to do that 100+ times…. Maaanual.